# PHP Array in to comma separated list

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a list of items from a database being parse in an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dToken] => 731fea87ea9dc61f16e93f1ad2b964bf1926633acac151c1853ab91ea0465228
            [0] => 731fea87ea9dc61f16e93f1ad2b964bf1926633acac151c1853ab91ea0465228
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dToken] => d890a5002f7da8bd35f6cae50e597d6f11554b26ba686bc7314afe77d1b36a61
            [0] => d890a5002f7da8bd35f6cae50e597d6f11554b26ba686bc7314afe77d1b36a61
        )

)
```

I need to get all of the dTokens and list them out in a variable with each dToken seperated by a comma except the last in the list.

```
foreach($result as $device['dToken'] => $token){
    //$devices = $token['dToken'];
    print_r($token['dToken']);
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I cannot get all of the dTokens out into one variable with the commas for reuse

Comment: @Blaine `join()` is an alias for `implode()`. Please just use `implode()` :)

Comment: @PeeHaa what's the difference?

Comment: @Blaine It is more clear when other people look at your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just about there.

```
$tokens = array();
foreach($result as $device){
    $tokens[] = $device['dToken'];
}
echo implode(',', $tokens);
```

Comment: THanks for this really helpful, just as an added bonus how would I warp each dToken in " " ?

Comment: `$tokens[] = '"'.$device['dToken'].'"';`

Answer (score 6):

You could just build the string:

```
$cvsString = '';
$delimiter = '';
foreach($result as $device){
    $cvsString.= $delimiter . $device['dToken'];

    $delimiter = ',';
}

var_dump($cvsString);
```

Or you could first build in array:

```
$cvsArray = array();
foreach($result as $device){
    $cvsArray[] = $device['dToken'];
}

var_dump(implode(',', $cvsArray));
```

Comment: you forgot the ',' in the first `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question corresponding to the tile (transform an Array to a list with separator) use the `implode` function. To generate a CSV I would google `php CSV`, I'm sure there are already lots of function to do it.

Comment: `join` is an alias for `implode`.

Comment: you are right, PHP is not my first language, so I use join (as lots of other language use 'join'). I'll edit my answer

Comment: However, why does PHP provide alias if you *can't* use them ? ;-)

Comment: +1 for the edit :) But serious when coding it is important to always try to prevent WTF's for other people reading / reviewing your code. Although it is not a big one it is always better to prevent it when possible. Besides PHP has a lot of WTFs already built-in so I always try to steer away from them when possible just to prevent confusion and errors. P.S. there was nothing "wrong" with your answer it could just be improved imho :)

Answer (score -1):

```
callback = function($row){
    return $row['dToken'];
}

implode(",",array_map(callback,$result));
```